# How to edit div content on button click using html and javascipt or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to edit div contents on edit click using javascript but on button click my paragraph tag does not edit nor focuses.

I have tried this code from w3schools but this code is not working for me.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myP").contenteditable = true;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The p element above is now editable. Try to change its text.";
}
```

```html
<p id="myP">This is a paragraph. Click the button to make me editable.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Do you see this line `document.getElementById("demo")` ? Also, should be `contentEditable ` or rather use `Element.setAttribute()`

Comment: Try setAttribute("contenteditable",true); demo:https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/n7a58tqx/20/

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript is case sensitive, the correct property is `contentEditable` and not `contenteditable`

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myP").contentEditable = true;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The p element above is now editable. Try to change its text.";
}
```

```html
<p id="myP">This is a paragraph. Click the button to make me editable.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

If you are not certain of the name of a property of an object you could iterate through all of its properties. Or use google/mdn to check the relevant page. i.e. [MDN HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement).

```js
for (var key in HTMLParagraphElement.prototype) {
  if (/content|edit/i.test(key)) console.log(key);
}
```

Most of the properties of HTML-elements can be accessed/altered using attributes and properties. In your case you could use `setAttribute("contenteditable", "true")`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myP").setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The p element above is now editable. Try to change its text.";
}
```

```html
<p id="myP">This is a paragraph. Click the button to make me editable.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Here is an approach that dynamically adds the event listener:

```js
document.getElementById("editMyP").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  document.getElementById("myP").contentEditable = true;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The p element above is now editable. Try to change its text.";
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<p id="myP">This is a paragraph. Click the button to make me editable.</p>
<button id="editMyP">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Side-note:

You stated that you were using w3schools, while they have kind of improved lately, I would advise you to use a different platform. You can read more on the why w3schools are frowned upon, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com).

Comment: thanks everyone..but still its not working

Comment: Hello @Meetali, Try pressing `Run code snippet` in the first block of my answer. Doesn't it work as expected in your browser?

Comment: i tried sir..but still not working i tried on different browser as well..its working here but not on my project

Comment: @Meetali Have you tried adding `console.log` statements before and after the `document.getElementById("myP").contentEditable = true;` to check if the code gets run properly?

Comment: Its not working because i am using asp.net and its having <form runat="server"> tag..when i remove this form tag its working

Comment: @Meetali I added another approach (check last block) that will dynamically add the event listener.

Comment: @Meetali Glad it worked. If my answer helped you can up-vote and/or accept it.